# Change text using hooks in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a very simple question. I am using hooks, and in the docs there is an example given to change the text using hooks. But there is place where I am not able to figure it out.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const HelloWorldApp = () => {

    const [textUpdate, setText] = useState('text1');
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{ text: 'Learn Hooks' }]);

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>{textUpdate}</Text>
                <Text>{todos.text}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default HelloWorldApp;
```

I can see `text1` on the screen, But I cant see `Learn hooks` on the screen. What is wrong with `<Text>{todos.text}</Text>` ??

**EDIT**

So I changed `<Text>{todos.text}</Text>` to `<Text>{todos[0].text}</Text>`.
Now I wanted to change the text on the click.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text>{textUpdate}</Text>
    <Text>{todos[0].text}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeText} >
        <Text>Click me</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

and also added changeText in the component.

```
const changeText = () => {
    if (textUpdate === 'text1' || todos[0].text === 'Learn') {
        setText('text2');
        setTodos({ text: 'done' })
    } else if (textUpdate === 'text2' || todos[0].text === 'done') {
        setText('text1');
        setTodos({ text: 'Learn' })
    }
}
```

It gives an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'todos[0].text')`

Comment: `todos` is an array. Did you mean `<Text>{todos[0].text}</Text>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ISSUE**

You have initialized state an array of object and reset it like object only

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Try using as an array of an object like

```
const changeText = () => {
    if (textUpdate === 'text1' || todos[0].text === 'Learn') {
        setText('text2');
        setTodos([{ text: 'done' }]) // add like array
    } else if (textUpdate === 'text2' || todos[0].text === 'done') {
        setText('text1');
        setTodos([{ text: 'Learn' }])  // add like array
    }
}
```

Comment: @pratteek shaurya I have updated my answer please check